# Application crash when accessing Coredata from Custom Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have moved all the business logics to a Custom framework project. As part of that, I have moved the xcdatamodeld also to the framework project. Even though I have moved the core data model to framework project, when I try to access the core data model object from the framework as given below, the app get crash.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
// The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"IHA" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

return _managedObjectModel;
```

}

What is happening in the above case is that modelURL is getting as nil. Can anyone suggest me the proper way of using CoreData in a custom framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you move you momd file in your framework bundle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've moved everything to your framework, your Core Data model is no longer in the main bundle of your app, it's in the framework's bundle.

In order to get that bundle from your framework you can do one of the following

```
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]; // Only works if the current class is part of your framework
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.yourframework.identifier"];
```

And then

```
NSURL *modelURL = [frameworkBundle URLForResource:@"IHA" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it resolved the issue for getting the reference of NSBundle. But still one more issue. I have XCTestTarget within my framework project. The unit test class is referring the DBManagerClass. There it is crashing with following exception. The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.

Comment: Uninstall your app and try again. You're going to have to do that every time you change the model.

Comment: When I tried with the unit test cases, which is still crashing. Is there any different way to write test cases with data base operation methods, when everything moved to framework project? When tried with the same unit test cases with the main project, which was working. This crash is happening only after moved to framework project.

Comment: It's probably possible yes. You should ask a new question about this issue, post your test code and the crash log

Comment: Hi deadbeef, I have the same problem. I am using Swift 4.2 with iOS 12. Could you please let me know how to load model from custom framework? I have my xcdatamodeld in custom framework.